# What is the remainder when $x^{100} -8x^{99}+12x^{98}-3x^{10}+24x^{9}-36x^{8}+3x^{2}-29x + 41$ is divided by: $x^2-8x+12$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification

What is the remainder when: $$x^{100} -8x^{99}+12x^{98}-3x^{10}+24x^{9}-36x^{8}+3x^{2}-29x + 41$$ is divided by: $$x^2-8x+12$$

$x^2-8x+12$ $\leftrightarrow (x-2)(x-6)$

This gives me the polynomial: $(x-2)(x-6)k(x) + r(x)$, where $r(x)$ is the remainder.

The expression gives me the remainder when $x=2$ or $x = 6$

By replacing $x$ with $2$ into the original polynomial you get: $$x^{100} - 4x^{100}+3x^{100}-3x^{10}+12x^{10}-9x^{10}+3x^{2}-29x + 41 = 3x^2-29x + 41$$

By plugging in $2$ I get: $12-58 + 41 = -5$.

Hence $r(x)$ should be: $-5$.

This is apparently the wrong answer. What did I do wrong?

Thank you kindly for your help!

Comment: "By entering $2$ into the original polynomial you get:" - don't you mean to replace $x$ with $2$?

Comment: Yes that is right, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: "Hence $r(x)=-5$". What you can conclude is that $r(2)=-5$.

Comment: You could start by noticing that the first three terms can be ignored.

Comment: +1 to OP for clearly writing out his problem and indicating his steps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First note that $r(x)=ax+b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb Z$
For $x=2$ you get $r(2)=-5$ (not $r(x)=-5$) $ \Rightarrow 2a+b=-5$. Do the same for $x=6$ to find r(6).Then find $a,b$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ You are very close to the solution. By the polynomial division algorithm

$$\begin{eqnarray} &&\rm f(x) &\: =\: &\rm a + bx + (x-2)(x-6)\, g(x)\\
\Rightarrow\ &&\rm f(2) &\:=\:&\rm a + 2b \\
\Rightarrow\ &&\rm f(6) &\:=\:&\rm a + 6b \end{eqnarray}$$

Solving the above two linear equations for $\rm\,a,b\,$ determines the remainder. Note that the system has a unique solution since the determinant $\ne 0,\,$ being the difference of the *distinct* evaluation points.

**Remark** $\ $ The same method extends from two points to $\rm\,n\,$ points, i.e. we can uniquely interpolate the degree $\rm < n\,$ remainder through any $\rm\,n\,$ distinct points because a polynomial of degree $\rm < n\,$ over a field  is determined uniquely by $\rm\,n\,$ values. Indeed, the above system of equations has  Vandermonde determinant equal to the product of the differences of the evaluation points, so it is be nonzero if the roots are distinct. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/231490/23500) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth noting that
$$
\begin{multline}
x^{100} -8x^{99}+12x^{98}-3x^{10}+24x^{9}-36x^{8}+3x^{2}-29x + 41\\
=x^{98}(x^2-8x+12)-3x^8(x^2-8x+12)+3(x^2-8x+12)-5x+5
\end{multline}
$$
so that the remainder is $-5x+5$.