# Powers of Complex Numbers Are Linearly Independent

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Suppose I have a set of distinct, nonzero complex numbers $\{z_1\,,...\,z_k\}\,,$ is there a quick way of arguing that if $$a_1z_1^n+\cdots a_kz_k^n=0$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}\,,$ then $$a_1=\cdots=a_k=0$$
?

If none of them have the same modulus then I can divide the whole equation by the highest modulus and send $n\to\infty\,,$ showing term by term that each coefficient is zero, so I have reduced the problem to $|z_i|=1$ for all $i\,.$ If $k=2$ this is simple but for arbitrary $k$ I'm not sure what is an efficient way to do it.

Comment: @Wojowu But the requirement is that it's zero for all $n\,.$

Comment: Ah, I'm terribly sorry, I've misread that as "for some $n$".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $$a_1z_1^n+\cdots + a_kz_k^n=0$$
for $n = 0, 1, \dots, k-1$, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
z_1 & z_2 & \dots & z_k\\
z_1^{2} & z_{2}^{2} & \dots & z_{k}^{2}\\
  & & \ddots \\
z_1^{k-1} & z_{2}^{k-1} & \dots & z_{k}^{k-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_k
\end{bmatrix} = 0,
$$
where the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) has nonzero determinant, as the $z_i$ are distinct. I use the fact that the $z_i$ are non-zero to determine the first row.

Comment: If one doesn't know the Vandermonde matrix: The OP asks for linear independence of the rows; this is equivalent to linear independence of the columns; and that simply expresses that a degree $k-1$ polynomial with $k$ distinct roots is the zero polynomial

Comment: Nice @Andreas! +1!

Comment: @OP see [also here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/231490/242) for an example of the view by Hagen.